# Sending Bitmap image to server with rest api

Tags: android, base64

I want to send an image to my server with rest api. For that, I am using

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 240 * bitmap.getWidth() / bitmap.getHeight(), 240, false);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

code block to create bitmap for my ImageView and encode my image to string. My image is 240x240. When I try to send it, server gives me [413](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413) response code. Could it be caused by server settings?

Comment: You did not post code that tries to send something to a server. Further you could tell what 413 means.

Comment: I told what 413 means above. Encoded string is too large. And I am asking why and is there an alternative way.

Comment: @YSFKBDY , you can try to send it as a file rather than the base64 string

Comment: `and is there an alternative way.` Well you did not post code that sends anything to a server. So we do not know which 'way' you use now. Hence impossible to suggest other ways. Further you should have told by now how many bytes are used for base64 encodedImage string.